# Adding KML layer with an image layer - Not Loading

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to add custom overlay & Kml layer. The custom layer is working, but the KML layer is not showing at all. What would cause this?

```
var overlay;
USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

// Initialize the map and the custom overlay.

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 16,
    center: {lat: 31.1917, lng: 27.56553},
    mapTypeId: 'satellite'
  });

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(31.18954, 27.56144),
      new google.maps.LatLng(31.19277, 27.56806));


  var srcImage = 'https://travcop.zohosites.com/selc02.png';


  overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
}

/** @constructor */
function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {

  // Initialize all properties.
  this.bounds_ = bounds;
  this.image_ = image;
  this.map_ = map;

  // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
  // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
  // method so we'll leave it null for now.
  this.div_ = null;

  // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay.
  this.setMap(map);
}

/**
 * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
 * added to the map.
 */
USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';

  // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.image_;
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = '100%';
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.appendChild(img);

  this.div_ = div;

  // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};

USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

  // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
};

  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'https://travcop.zohosites.com/sel.kml',
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    map: map
  });


  function showInContentWindow(text) {
    var sidediv = document.getElementById('content-window');
    sidediv.innerHTML = text;
  }
// The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
// we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
  this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
  this.div_ = null;
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

I am not sure why the KML layer is not loading. Could be the two layers loading in the same time?

Trying to create a real estate portal where data is marked in KML and the map is for a future project that is not yet displayed on Google Maps

Answer (score 0):

I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined`.

The `map` variable is local to your `initMap` function, you need to instantiate the `KmlLayer` inside your `initMap` method.

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 16,
    center: {lat: 31.1917, lng: 27.56553},
    mapTypeId: 'satellite'
  });

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(31.18954, 27.56144),
      new google.maps.LatLng(31.19277, 27.56806));

  var srcImage = 'https://travcop.zohosites.com/selc02.png';

  overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);

  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'https://travcop.zohosites.com/sel.kml',
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    preserveViewport: true,
    map: map
  });
}
```

Once I fix that, there is another error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: overlayProjection is not defined`, because `overlayProjection` isn't defined.  Taking the definition from [Google's example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays) fixes that.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zv3t6850/7/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var overlay;
USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

// Initialize the map and the custom overlay.

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 16,
    center: {
      lat: 31.1917,
      lng: 27.56553
    },
    mapTypeId: 'satellite'
  });

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(31.18954, 27.56144),
    new google.maps.LatLng(31.19277, 27.56806));


  var srcImage = 'https://travcop.zohosites.com/selc02.png';


  overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);

  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'https://travcop.zohosites.com/sel.kml',
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    preserveViewport: true,
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'status_changed', function() {
    console.log(kmlLayer.getStatus());
  })
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

/** @constructor */
function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {

  // Initialize all properties.
  this.bounds_ = bounds;
  this.image_ = image;
  this.map_ = map;

  // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
  // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
  // method so we'll leave it null for now.
  this.div_ = null;

  // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay.
  this.setMap(map);
}

/**
 * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
 * added to the map.
 */
USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';

  // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.image_;
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = '100%';
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.appendChild(img);

  this.div_ = div;

  // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};

USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

  // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
};



function showInContentWindow(text) {
  var sidediv = document.getElementById('content-window');
  sidediv.innerHTML = text;
}
// The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
// we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
  this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
  this.div_ = null;
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```